# Не выводит русские символы

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

   cout << "Привет";

   system("PAUSE");

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Это настолько избитая тема, что в Гугле тонны ссылок на этот счет. Проверьте Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Administrative -> Change System Locale.

    [root@host tmp]# cat > c.cpp
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main ()
    { 
    cout << "Привет" << endl;
    return 0;
    }

    [root@host tmp]# g++ c.cpp 
    [root@host tmp]# ./a.out
    Привет
    [root@host tmp]#

Comment: У тебя в никсах UTF-8 в системе стоит, а у него CP-1251.

Comment: А он где-нибудь указал, что использует Windows?

Comment: Да, system("PAUSE");. Win'довый костыль (насколько мне известно).

Comment: Верно, не поспоришь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**вариант 1**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <locale>//

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");//

    cout << "Привет";
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

---

**вариант 2**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <Windows.h>//

using namespace std;

int main(){
    SetConsoleCP(1251);//
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);//

    cout << "Привет";
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

---

**вариант 3**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <Windows.h>//не помню какой из двух надо подрубить   
#include <locale>//и надо ли вообще

using namespace std;

int main(){
    system("chcp 1251");//

    cout << "Привет";
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

---

так же, толи во всех, толи в некоторых надо поменять шрифт в консоле на Lucida Console

**update**

это всё работает на вывод текста в коде, на ввод и вывод из консоли работает вроде только 2-й (3-й не проверял)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сохранить исходники в utf-8. Должно помочь.

Comment: Странный совет. Но тема -- кириллица в консоли виндов здесь периодически всплывает. Чаще проблемы с кодировкой cp1251/cp866